# Is the character § supported by CCSID 1208

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I need to know if the character  § is supported by CCSID 1208. In general, How do we find the list of characters supported by a particular CCSID.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As nitgeek said, yes, it's supported and 1208 is UTF-8 (level 3).

Here is a [list of IBM's CCSID's](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/ccsid/ccsid_registered.html). You can drill down to see the code pages - for instance here's the code page for [37 (US/Canada)](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/cp/cp00037.html).

The above links are no longer valid. [This link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=information-ccsid-reference) is specific to the IBM i platform but the information should be consistent for all IBM products. This link is valid as of December 24, 2023.

Comment: The links are broke if you could update it would be apreciated.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is supported.

FYI, CCSID 1208 is equivalent to UTF-8.

Here are the characters supported by UTF-8 [UTF-8 supported characters](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)